Maplibre setLayoutProperty triggered flash of map layer
When user try to change visible of geojson layer, other layers on a map was flashed. It happend in a vector tiles
example:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/maplibre-n5hcw8?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue%3A38%2C31
I dont have idea. I try remove/add source and layers instead change visibility properties. But map flashed

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
